# List all webservices (SOAP/REST) deployed in the web server

Tags: java, web-services

I have a wsdl file as below and would like to know if there is a possibility to display the list of webservices in the browser via jsp or any other front end technology..

This is using SOAP, also i would like to know if there are similar ways to display the list of web services using REST as well.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI          2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
    <definitions targetNamespace="http://test.com/" name="HelloWorldNewService"        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://test.com/" schemaLocation="HelloWorldNewService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="sum">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sum"/>
  </message>
  <message name="sumResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sumResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="HelloWorldNew">
    <operation name="sum">
      <input message="tns:sum"/>
      <output message="tns:sumResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="HelloWorldNewPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorldNew">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="sum">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="HelloWorldNewService">
    <port name="HelloWorldNewPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldNewPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/CustomWebservices/HelloWorldNew"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

**[UPDATE]**
I need to replicate soemthing like Eclipse Web Services explorer wherein I will have a front end displaying the set of webservices and by hitting on the each of the web services name it should show me the list of paramns and stuffs like that.

Comment: Do you want to display the list of operations of the web service, like "sum" or the web service name "HelloWorldNewService" ?

Comment: Luciano, I would like to show the ws name and then when i hit the ws name, it should populate the method sum along with the params.. Just like the Eclipse Webservices Explorer..

Comment: Any comments on this please?